# Best way to call C-functions from python?

Tags: python, c

I've written a high level motor controller in Python, and have got to a point where I want to go a little lower level to get some speed, so I'm interested in coding those bits in C.

I don't have much experience with C, but the math I'm working on is pretty straightforward, so I'm sure I can implement with a minimal amount of banging my head against the wall. What I'm not sure about is how best to invoke this compiled C program in order to pipe it's outputs back into my high-level python controller.

I've used a little bit of ctypes, but only to pull some functions from a manufacfturer-supplied DLL...not sure if that is an appropriate path to go down in this case.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Seems similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145270/calling-c-c-from-python

Comment: You may also want to have a look at Cython.  It's built for pretty much exactly this purpose and you may not even have to change your code very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at this tutorial [here](http://csl.name/C-functions-from-Python/).

Also, a more reliable example on the official python website, [here](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html#a-simple-example).

For example,

`sum.h` function

```
int sum(int a, int b)
```

A file named, `module.c`,

```
#include <Python.h>
#include "sum.h"

static PyObject* mod_sum(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int s;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args,"ii",&a,&b))
       return NULL;
    s = sum(a,b);
    return Py_BuildValue("i",s);
}

static PyMethodDef ModMethods[] = {
    {"sum", mod_sum, METH_VARARGS, "Description.."},
    {NULL,NULL,0,NULL}
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC initmod(void)
{
    PyObject *m;
    m = Py_InitModule("module",ModMethods);
    if (m == NULL)
       return;
}
```

Python

```
import module
s = module.sum(3,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option: try [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/).
It gives you C-like speed for free: just import numba and @autojit your functions, for a wonderful speed increase.

Won't work if you have complicated data types, but if you're looping and jumping around array indices, it might be just what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you can use SWIG, it is very simple to use

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cython for setting the necessary c types and compile your python syntax code.